# Cognitive Complexity and its effect on the code

Tags: java, algorithm, mapreduce, refactoring, sonarlint

W.r.t to one of the java projects, we recently started using SonarLint. Output of the code analysis shows too many critical code smell alerts.

```
Critical code smell: Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity.
```

I have heard about Cyclomatic Complexity but not about Cognitive Complexity.
My questions to the group:

- Is Cognitive Complexity an industry standard?
- Impacts of Cognitive Complexity on code apart from readability and maintainability.
- Does Cognitive Complexity apply only to methods or any other parts of code?
- Any specific criteria on which Cognitive Complexity depends on?
- Best practices to improve Cognitive Complexity of a code.

I have gone through this [link](https://blog.sonarsource.com/cognitive-complexity-because-testability-understandability) but could not get answers to all my questions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That link also includes a link to a white paper on the subject with more details. Have you gone through that too?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that. I had missed. Info in that white paper looks to be sufficient for a developer to have a decent understanding of Cognitive Complexity and how to approach it.

Comment: You can also have a look at this answer for an explanation of how cognitive complexity is calculated and how it be reduced: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62867219/7730554

Answer (score 37):

Humans can easily keep in mind about 7 entities +/- 2([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magical_Number_Seven,_Plus_or_Minus_Two)).
When somebody needs to read the code they may run into this limit. Sometimes there are too many local variables to keep track of, or too many if/for statements. In all cases it makes it harder to understand what the code is supposed to do because it's hard to keep a mental picture of the algorithm.

Industry standard: No.

Readability and maintainability: It's easier to debug/improve code that is simple and easy to read.

Applies on methods or other parts: Everything that some human might want to understand. If you try to explain your design and I need to keep track of 20+ classes, I'll be lost. If I need to work quickly with your interface but I need to remember 10 bits of state, I won't be able to.

Any specific criteria it depends on: The amount of things one needs to remember to understand the code.

Best practices: Make more and better defined functions. Extract related concepts into groups/packages. Reduce the number of nesting levels in the code (if you read a nested code you need to remember the condition that got you there). Reduce the number of in use variables at any one point (works great with extracting functions).

Comment: With your comments, it looks like we can apply Cognitive Complexity in any field, not only just coding. Let me explore its applicability in different aspects. Thanks.