# How to refactor this function to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 17 to the 15 allowed

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, sonarqube, refactoring

- How to refactor this function to reduce the complexicity
- When I am using switch case at that time code complixity is more so how to reduce it

  > > How to achive this

```
var has = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty



var toString = Object.prototype.toString


function isEmpty(val) {
 
  if (val == null) return true
  if ('boolean' == typeof val) return false
  if ('number' == typeof val) return val === 0
  if ('string' == typeof val) return val.length === 0
  if ('function' == typeof val) return val.length === 0
  if (Array.isArray(val)) return val.length === 0
  if (val instanceof Error) return val.message === ''
  if (val.toString == toString) {
    switch (val.toString()) {
      case '[object File]':
      case '[object Map]':
      case '[object Set]': {
        return val.size === 0
      }
      case '[object Object]': {
        for (var key in val) {
          if (has.call(val, key)) return false
        }

        return true
      }
    }
  }
  return false
}
module.exports = isEmpty
```

Comment: `if ('function' == typeof val) return val.length === 0`? How is a a function that takes no arguments "empty"?

Comment: `if (val instanceof Error) return val.message === ''` similar, I guess - if an error doesn't have a message I wouldn't consider it *empty*. The fact that *it's an error* conveys intention and information by itself. Furthermore, you can have different subtypes of Error that convey information themselves, e.g., if you get `DivisionByZeroError` that hardly needs a message.

Comment: `if (val.toString == toString)` this check seems wrong. At least because you can just use `instanceof` to check for Map, Set, and File.

Answer (score 2):

I recently gave an answer to a very similar question going a little more into detail about how cognitive complexity works (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62867219/7730554).

But in general, I think it is important to understand that **cognitive complexity is increased even more if there are nested conditions**. This calculation is done this way because the human brain can deal a lot better with statements written in sequence rather than with nested conditions. So for each conditional statement (if, switch, for loop, etc.) there will be a +1 added to the complexity value. But for each nested condition another +1 is added on top of the last level. That means, an if inside an if will not only add +1, but +2. An if, inside an if, inside an if will than result in +1 for the first if, +2 for the second and +3 for the third if condition. If you want to dig deeper into this I recommend taking a look at: https://www.sonarsource.com/docs/CognitiveComplexity.pdf

So let's analyze where the high complexity values from your method originate first:

```
function isEmpty(val) {
    if (val == null) return true // +1 
    if ('boolean' == typeof val) return false // +1
    if ('number' == typeof val) return val === 0 // +1
    if ('string' == typeof val) return val.length === 0 // +1
    if ('function' == typeof val) return val.length === 0 // +1
    if (Array.isArray(val)) return val.length === 0 // +1
    if (val instanceof Error) return val.message === '' // +1
    if (val.toString == toString) { // +1
        switch (val.toString()) { // +2
            case '[object File]':
            case '[object Map]':
            case '[object Set]': {
                return val.size === 0
            }
            case '[object Object]': {
                for (var key in val) { // +3
                    if (has.call(val, key)) return false // +4
                }

                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

If you look at the comments I added you can easily see where the most problematic code concerning cyclomatic complexity is located. This also relates to the human readabilty of the code.

So one simply step to **increase readability** and at the same time **reduce congnitive complexity** is to look for options of "***early returns***".

To illustrate this, I simply inverted the statement *if (val.toString == toString)" to immediately return false if *val.toString != toString":

```
function isEmpty(val) {
    if (val == null) return true // +1 
    if ('boolean' == typeof val) return false // +1
    if ('number' == typeof val) return val === 0 // +1
    if ('string' == typeof val) return val.length === 0 // +1
    if ('function' == typeof val) return val.length === 0 // +1
    if (Array.isArray(val)) return val.length === 0 // +1
    if (val instanceof Error) return val.message === '' // +1
    if (val.toString != toString) { // +1
        return false;
    }
    
    switch (val.toString()) { // +1
        case '[object File]':
        case '[object Map]':
        case '[object Set]': {
            return val.size === 0
        }
        case '[object Object]': {
            for (var key in val) { // +2
                if (has.call(val, key)) return false // +3
            }
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Now the last switch statement can be executed outside the if statement and we reduced the nesting level by one. With that simple change the cognitive **complexity** has now **dropped to 14** instead of 17.

You could then even go a step further and change the last case statement by extracting the return value into a variable and either extract a separate method out of the code block. This would reduce the complexity of the isEmpty() method even more.

And besides from extracting a method you can also use a declarative approach and use, for instance the Array method *find()* which would reduce the cognitive complexity even more.

To illustrate the idea I did both:

```
function isEmpty(val) {
    if (val == null) return true // +1 
    if ('boolean' == typeof val) return false // +1
    if ('number' == typeof val) return val === 0 // +1
    if ('string' == typeof val) return val.length === 0 // +1
    if ('function' == typeof val) return val.length === 0 // +1
    if (Array.isArray(val)) return val.length === 0 // +1
    if (val instanceof Error) return val.message === '' // +1
    if (val.toString != toString) { // +1
        return false;
    }
    
    return checkForComplexTypes(val)
}

function checkForComplexTypes(val) {
    var result = null
    switch (val.toString()) { // +1
        case '[object File]':
        case '[object Map]':
        case '[object Set]': {
            result = val.size === 0
        }
        case '[object Object]': {
            result = Object.keys(val).find(key => has.call(val, key))
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

This should **bring down the cognitive complexity** of the *isEmpty()* method **to 8** and the **whole code** including the extracted *checkForComplexTypes()* function **to a complexity score of 9**.

Note: JavaScript is not my major language at the moment so I cannot fully guarantee the correctness of the last refactoring step.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot split the function or use OOP approach, you can use array of functions and iterate over it:

```js
const has = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
const toString = Object.prototype.toString;

function isEmpty(val) {
    let isEmpty = null;

    const checkFunctions = [
        (val) => 'boolean' === typeof val ? false : null,
        (val) => 'number' === typeof val ? val === 0 : null,
        (val) => ['string', 'function'].includes(typeof val) ? val.length === 0 : null,
        (val) => Array.isArray(val) ? val.length === 0 : null,

        (val) => val instanceof Error ? val.message === '' : null,

        (val) => val.toString == toString && ['[object File]', '[object Map]', '[object Set]'].includes(val.toString()) ? val.size === 0 : null,
        (val) => {
            if (val.toString == toString && val.toString() === '[object Object]') {
                for (var key in val) {
                    if (has.call(val, key)) return false
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    ];

    for (let i = 0; i < checkFunctions.length; i++) {
        isEmpty = checkFunctions[i](val);
        if (isEmpty !== null) {
            return isEmpty;
        };
    }
}

console.log(isEmpty(''), true);
console.log(isEmpty('Hallo'), false);
console.log(isEmpty(0), true);
console.log(isEmpty(1), false);
console.log(isEmpty({}), true);
console.log(isEmpty({a: 1}), false);
```

You can also extend core types of JS and then instead of isEmpty(val) write val.isEmpty(). For example:

```js
String.prototype.isEmpty = function() {return this.length === 0}
Array.prototype.isEmpty = function() {return this.length === 0}

console.log("".isEmpty(), true);
console.log("foo".isEmpty(), false);
console.log([].isEmpty(), true);
console.log([1,2,3].isEmpty(), false);
```